pyudev - How to use asynchronous callbacks?
if we read this, We can detect USB connected/disconnected using pyUdev

https://pyudev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#asynchronous-monitoring

using this sample, When USB = connect/disable timing, the callback ( usbDeviceEventHandler ) is called. this is good.
self.observer = pyudev.MonitorObserver(monitor, usbDeviceEventHandler)
self.observer.start() 

but there is problem...
async def usbDeviceEventHandler  
  ....

To use "asynchronous" callback is not possible..
it not work correctly...
Do you have any idea ?

The handler can communicate with an async task. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading

The handler itself must be a sync function, but it can create an asyncio Task:
def usbDeviceEventHandler():

    async def aHandler():
        # do async things here, concurrently with other Tasks

    asyncio.create_task(aHandler())

